# Spannable array from string resource

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, spannable

Is there  a way to extract a `Spannable[] stuff` from string resource? Basically something similar to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Welcome to <b>Mercury</b></item>
    <item>Welcome to <b>Venus</b></item>
    <item>Welcome to <b>Earth</b></item>
    <item>Welcome to <b>Mars</b></item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then I would extract the array into

```
Resources res = getResources();
Spannable[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

But right now eclipse is telling me to change `Spannable[]` to `String[]`.

Comment: @pskink Thanks, but it didn’t work. When I do `Spannable[] stuff = (Spannable[]) res.getTextArray(R.array.stuff_array)` I get the error
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.CharSequence[] cannot be cast to android.text.Spannable[]`. I may have to do something more lengthy to construct my Spannable array.

Comment: try to cast not the whole array but particular items like stuff[0]

Comment: that didn't work either, but then I figured that I could just use `CharSequence` to capture the formatting and that I didn't need to convert to Spannable. I could not do it without your suggestion to use `getTextArray` so I would like to give the credit to you. Do you mind posting as response so I may mark this thread as resolved? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use getTextArray, it returns CharSequence[] instead of String[] which preserves attached spans